# Поиск ФИО или даты в тексте

Tags: машинное-обучение, поиск, текст

Есть распознанный (разные источники, документы-чеки, на русском) текст, нужно в этом тексте находить ФИО и даты.
Использование меток а-ля фио идет после слова "фио:" не всегда работает, ибо иногда искомое фио непредсказуемом месте (в комментариях к платежу, например).
Поиск именованных сущностей вроде из пушки по воробьям, да еще и текст по сути набор несвязанных слов.

Тупое решение: регулярные выражения, но для имен они зло по своей сути. :)

Вообще хотелось бы использовать машинное обучение, дабы сдать как курсовик по соответствующему предмету, но как подступиться - я не понимаю. Если есть решение без машинки - тоже пригодится, задачу в любом случае надо решить.
Даты по наличию года находить получается, но с ними наверное ML проще чем с ФИО применить.

Comment: Для Python есть библиотека [Natasha](https://github.com/natasha/natasha) для извлечения фактов из текста (ФИО, дат, адресов и т.д.)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего с регулярками будет проще сделать. Либо с `NER`, например из библиотеки `Natasha`. Когда вы осознаете все сложности, с которыми вам придётся столкнуться при попытке решения этой задачи методами машинного обучения, вы поймёте, что это как-раз машинное обучение тут "из пушки по воробьям", а не наоборот.

Если машинное обучение использовать нужно принципиально, то вам придётся:

- придумать какие-то фичи, которые позволили бы алгоритму ML отделить ФИО от других сущностей; придумывание фич - это отдельное искусство, там может быть что угодно - длина слова, длина предыдущего слова, наличие большой первой буквы в слове, ну там полно всего придётся придумать
- разметить данные !!!! т.е. вручную прописать, что тут - фио, а тут - не фио, это очень нудная и кропотливая работа
- гонять получившиеся данные разными алгоритмами ML, допридумывать фичи, доразмечать данные...

Это долгий и сложный процесс. Но интересный, конечно.

Comment: Не понимаю как раньше не попалась Наташа, но сейчас затестила: в "человеческом тексте" она нормально распознает имена,  а вот несвязанных данных с чека - только если написан адекватный комментарий "оплата от Пупкина Васи"

Comment: @Cactus566 Можете попробовать ещё `pymorphy2` использовать - определять тип речи слов, например. Но в целом задача непростая по-любому. В длинных текстах ФИО определять это одно, а в коротких - ну, такое. Приведите примеры что там в "несвязных данных с чека", что есть ФИО, а Наташа не понимает, что это ФИО.

Comment: "КВИТАНЦИЯ ОБ ОПЛАТЕ ООО НЛО ПЛАТЕЛЬЩИК: ПУПКИН ИВАН ВАСИЛЬЕВИЧ ОСНОВАНИЕ: 00000000000  НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ: ОПЛАТА ЗА ЕДУ ТРАНЗАКЦИЯ: 00003  ДАТА ТРАНЗАКЦИИ: 21.05.2020Г.  СУММА: 1500.00 РУБ." - наташа ничего не находит. (Но тут как раз по "плательшик:" инфа ищется. Видимо, буду комбинировать. )

Comment: @Cactus566 вот не сказал бы, что тут прям несвязанные данные, наоборот вполне понятная структура (вариантов текста квитанции может быть несколько, но скорее всего они более-менее типовые). Можно модуль [parse](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse) использовать, получится что-то такое: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeCY8.png